# In yii how to find out number votes

Tags: php, yii

i am creating project in yii. I am having 3 tables as-
poll                  Option             Pollvote
-PollId              -optionId           -voteId
-PollQuestion        -option             -optionId
                     -pollId             -createdate

One question may have 4 or 5 options.
Suppose i have data as-
        PollId=1     PollQuestion="Who is best Player"
        optionId=1   option=ABC
        optionId=2   option=DEF
        optionId=3   option=XYZ
Now these options are having different number of votes. I want to display highest voting option.
I had designed function for getting question and its related options as-

```
 public function actionpublishPollResult()
{
    $model=new Polloption();
    $json='{"pollId":1}';
    $obj=json_decode($json);
    $model->pollId=$obj->pollId;
    $record=Polloption::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('pollId'=>$model->pollId));
    foreach ($record as $option)
    {
        echo "option id :-".$option->optionId."<br>";

    } }
```

Its giving me output as-
option id :-3
option id :-5
option id :-6
option id :-7

So now how to access single optionId and how to find out number of votes for each option.
Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wanna order your options by the most voted why don't you query the database for all the options of that PollId, and order them by the votes_counter column DESC ??

then in your view just loop it.

PS - this is a php design problem. not a yii framework specific problem. for a better change to get help you should tag your questions better.

Comment: Thanx for suggestion sir....                                   But following code is giving all options together at time.          foreach ($record as $option)
    {
        echo "option id :-".$option->optionId."<br>";

    }             How to access each of separate optionId so that i can fire query on database where questionId= some specific optionid. Please help me

Comment: on a mysql server, try this query -> SELECT * from tbl_options WHERE pollId = XX ORDER BY column_number_of_votes DESC  - with this query you'll get all options rows that belongs to pollid XX ordered by the column_number_of_votes DESCENDING (meaning from the highest number down)